# How to parse Youtube Playlist into ArrayList

Tags: java, android, json, youtube, gdata

I am `parsing` simple **JSON** as shown below:

```
if (status == 200) {
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);                 

    JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
    JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("actors");

    for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

        Actors actor = new Actors();

        actor.setName(object.getString("name"));                        
        actor.setImage(object.getString("image"));

        actorsList.add(actor);
    }
    return true;
}
```

And here is the `JSON` link using **AsyncTask** to execute:

```
 new JSONAsyncTask().execute("http://microblogging.wingnity.com/JSONParsingTutorial/jsonActors");
```

But now i have to `parse Youtube JSON Playlist`:

```
 http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PLWz5rJ2EKKc9ofd2f-_-xmUi07wIGZa1c?v=2&alt=jsonc
```

I need to fetch few things, like: `Title`, `Thumbnail`, `Link` of each and every **Video**

**Pojo:**

```
public class Actors {

    private String name;    
    private String image;

    public Actors() {

    }

    public Actors(String name, String image) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.image = image;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the Json format you are trying to parse? Or am I missing the question? (the youtube link returns 410)

Comment: @Danielson actually i also don't know youtube playlist json format..

Comment: I found this answer, http://stackoverflow.com/a/6560844/928952 hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You get response like this (**IMPT** *PlayingList Response using ChannelId (query parameter))*

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#playlistListResponse",
 "etag": "\"Y3xTLFF3RLtHXX85JBgzzgp2Enw/O8-3nTBpPVrsEjyg6BXeSSO2pU0\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 3,
  "resultsPerPage": 5
 },
 "items": [
  {

   "kind": "youtube#playlist",
   "etag": "\"Y3xTLFF3RLtHXX85JBgzzgp2Enw/06IYq1oWiveiXSEbF8J6Ucf9LYs\"",
   "id": "PLFE56E5CE58D71A55",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2012-04-05T17:01:18.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCjXfkj5iapKHJrhYfAF9ZGg",
    "title": "T&T Elite Canada 2012, April 4, 2012",
    "description": "",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/default.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/default.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/default.jpg"
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "AlbertaGymnastics",
    "localized": {
     "title": "T&T Elite Canada 2012, April 4, 2012",
     "description": ""
    }
   }
  }, ... and more items..}
```

Now create a pojo for above json response and read video details from `items` array

Comment: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PLWz5rJ2EKKc9ofd2f-_-xmUi07wIGZa1c?v=2&alt=jsonc and getting: {"apiVersion":"2.1","error":{"code":410,"message":"No longer available","errors":[{"domain":"GData","code":"NoLongerAvailableException","internalReason":"No longer available"}]}} and i have made changes in my code as per requirement to fetch JSON response, but not getting any data...

Comment: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=snippet&channelId=UCjXfkj5iapKHJrhYfAF9ZGg&key={YOUR_API_KEY}... this url i used from YoutubeData API Reference...

Comment: Don't know but I guess `gdata.youtube.com` deprecated... visit https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/

Answer (score 0):

Based on @bharat's answer (note different Classes)

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "url" })
public class Default {

    @JsonProperty("url")
    private String url;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    /**
     * 
     * @return The url
     */
    @JsonProperty("url")
    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param url
     *            The url
     */
    @JsonProperty("url")
    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }

}


package com.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "kind", "etag", "pageInfo", "items" })
public class Example {

    @JsonProperty("kind")
    private String kind;
    @JsonProperty("etag")
    private String etag;
    @JsonProperty("pageInfo")
    private PageInfo pageInfo;
    @JsonProperty("items")
    private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    /**
     * 
     * @return The kind
     */
    @JsonProperty("kind")
    public String getKind() {
        return kind;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param kind
     *            The kind
     */
    @JsonProperty("kind")
    public void setKind(String kind) {
        this.kind = kind;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return The etag
     */
    @JsonProperty("etag")
    public String getEtag() {
        return etag;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param etag
     *            The etag
     */
    @JsonProperty("etag")
    public void setEtag(String etag) {
        this.etag = etag;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return The pageInfo
     */
    @JsonProperty("pageInfo")
    public PageInfo getPageInfo() {
        return pageInfo;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param pageInfo
     *            The pageInfo
     */
    @JsonProperty("pageInfo")
    public void setPageInfo(PageInfo pageInfo) {
        this.pageInfo = pageInfo;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return The items
     */
    @JsonProperty("items")
    public List<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param items
     *            The items
     */
    @JsonProperty("items")
    public void setItems(List<Item> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }

}


import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "url" })
public class High {

    @JsonProperty("url")
    private String url;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    /**
     * 
     * @return The url
     */
    @JsonProperty("url")
    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param url
     *            The url
     */
    @JsonProperty("url")
    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }

}


import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "kind", "etag", "id", "snippet" })
public class Item {

    @JsonProperty("kind")
    private String kind;
    @JsonProperty("etag")
    private String etag;
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private String id;
    @JsonProperty("snippet")
    private Snippet snippet;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    /**
     * 
     * @return The kind
     */
    @JsonProperty("kind")
    public String getKind() {
        return kind;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param kind
     *            The kind
     */
    @JsonProperty("kind")
    public void setKind(String kind) {
        this.kind = kind;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return The etag
     */
    @JsonProperty("etag")
    public String getEtag() {
        return etag;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param etag
     *            The etag
     */
    @JsonProperty("etag")
    public void setEtag(String etag) {
        this.etag = etag;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return The id
     */
    @JsonProperty("id")
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param id
     *            The id
     */
    @JsonProperty("id")
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return The snippet
     */
    @JsonProperty("snippet")
    public Snippet getSnippet() {
        return snippet;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param snippet
     *            The snippet
     */
    @JsonProperty("snippet")
    public void setSnippet(Snippet snippet) {
        this.snippet = snippet;
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }

}   

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "title", "description" })
public class Localized {

    @JsonProperty("title")
    private String title;
    @JsonProperty("description")
    private String description;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    /**
     * 
     * @return The title
     */
    @JsonProperty("title")
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param title
     *            The title
     */
    @JsonProperty("title")
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return The description
     */
    @JsonProperty("description")
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param description
     *            The description
     */
    @JsonProperty("description")
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }

}

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "url" })
public class Medium {

    @JsonProperty("url")
    private String url;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    /**
     * 
     * @return The url
     */
    @JsonProperty("url")
    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param url
     *            The url
     */
    @JsonProperty("url")
    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }

}


import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "totalResults", "resultsPerPage" })
public class PageInfo {

    @JsonProperty("totalResults")
    private Integer totalResults;
    @JsonProperty("resultsPerPage")
    private Integer resultsPerPage;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    /**
     * 
     * @return The totalResults
     */
    @JsonProperty("totalResults")
    public Integer getTotalResults() {
        return totalResults;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param totalResults
     *            The totalResults
     */
    @JsonProperty("totalResults")
    public void setTotalResults(Integer totalResults) {
        this.totalResults = totalResults;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return The resultsPerPage
     */
    @JsonProperty("resultsPerPage")
    public Integer getResultsPerPage() {
        return resultsPerPage;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param resultsPerPage
     *            The resultsPerPage
     */
    @JsonProperty("resultsPerPage")
    public void setResultsPerPage(Integer resultsPerPage) {
        this.resultsPerPage = resultsPerPage;
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }

}


import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "publishedAt", "channelId", "title", "description", "thumbnails", "channelTitle", "localized" })
public class Snippet {

    @JsonProperty("publishedAt")
    private String publishedAt;
    @JsonProperty("channelId")
    private String channelId;
    @JsonProperty("title")
    private String title;
    @JsonProperty("description")
    private String description;
    @JsonProperty("thumbnails")
    private Thumbnails thumbnails;
    @JsonProperty("channelTitle")
    private String channelTitle;
    @JsonProperty("localized")
    private Localized localized;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    /**
     * 
     * @return The publishedAt
     */
    @JsonProperty("publishedAt")
    public String getPublishedAt() {
        return publishedAt;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param publishedAt
     *            The publishedAt
     */
    @JsonProperty("publishedAt")
    public void setPublishedAt(String publishedAt) {
        this.publishedAt = publishedAt;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return The channelId
     */
    @JsonProperty("channelId")
    public String getChannelId() {
        return channelId;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param channelId
     *            The channelId
     */
    @JsonProperty("channelId")
    public void setChannelId(String channelId) {
        this.channelId = channelId;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return The title
     */
    @JsonProperty("title")
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param title
     *            The title
     */
    @JsonProperty("title")
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return The description
     */
    @JsonProperty("description")
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param description
     *            The description
     */
    @JsonProperty("description")
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return The thumbnails
     */
    @JsonProperty("thumbnails")
    public Thumbnails getThumbnails() {
        return thumbnails;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param thumbnails
     *            The thumbnails
     */
    @JsonProperty("thumbnails")
    public void setThumbnails(Thumbnails thumbnails) {
        this.thumbnails = thumbnails;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return The channelTitle
     */
    @JsonProperty("channelTitle")
    public String getChannelTitle() {
        return channelTitle;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param channelTitle
     *            The channelTitle
     */
    @JsonProperty("channelTitle")
    public void setChannelTitle(String channelTitle) {
        this.channelTitle = channelTitle;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return The localized
     */
    @JsonProperty("localized")
    public Localized getLocalized() {
        return localized;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param localized
     *            The localized
     */
    @JsonProperty("localized")
    public void setLocalized(Localized localized) {
        this.localized = localized;
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }

}

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "default", "medium", "high" })
public class Thumbnails {

    @JsonProperty("default")
    private Default _default;
    @JsonProperty("medium")
    private Medium medium;
    @JsonProperty("high")
    private High high;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    /**
     * 
     * @return The _default
     */
    @JsonProperty("default")
    public Default getDefault() {
        return _default;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param _default
     *            The default
     */
    @JsonProperty("default")
    public void setDefault(Default _default) {
        this._default = _default;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return The medium
     */
    @JsonProperty("medium")
    public Medium getMedium() {
        return medium;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param medium
     *            The medium
     */
    @JsonProperty("medium")
    public void setMedium(Medium medium) {
        this.medium = medium;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return The high
     */
    @JsonProperty("high")
    public High getHigh() {
        return high;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param high
     *            The high
     */
    @JsonProperty("high")
    public void setHigh(High high) {
        this.high = high;
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }

}
```

Or DIY for instance using http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/